# How to create an editable textbox in HTML that looks and function like a printed text box with lines?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a editable textbox with HTML/CSS/Javascript that looks and functions like a printed textbox with lines appearing every row.

It must look like this because the form may be printed on paper for people to write in.

I see three approaches to this method:

1. Table row with 'border-bottom' on each row and using javascript to determine when the text-overflows and move the cursor to the input box on the next row when it does.
   This method is probably not very accurate.
2. Drawing absolute-positioned lines beneath the div/textarea that contains the text.
3. Using CSS3 repeating gradients to draw the lines behind the div/textarea. Like so: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/lets-create-paper-with-css/
   . This method is only compatible with modern browsers though.

Which method is the best and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here’s one option](http://jsbin.com/ofemid/3). You need a `div` to draw each line, that could be done beforehand or with JavaScript.

In short, set an explicit line height on your `textarea`, then absolutely position a container element behind it. Inside that container put a set of elements with a height equal to the line height of the `textarea`, a one-pixel bottom border, and a negative-one-pixel bottom margin.

It’s most similar to your #2 but a little simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS3 method is best I think. As a fallback for browser that don't support it, you could put a background image of a line there, repeat it both horizontally and vertically, and use CSS to set the font size and line height so the typing aligns with the background image lines.

Comment: A background image would not work, as the users will be able to change the font-size. The background lines need to match the line-height.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the CSS3 method would at least let you use relative sizing like ems so people who've resized their fonts will still be ok. If it's not available in older browsers, I don't think that's hugely important, as it's an enhancement to make things easier *if* people print, rather than something that is essential to people interacting with the textarea.

Absolutely positioned lines might get un-aligned if the user resizes their browser/fonts/etc, although I haven't tested this to confirm. The Javascript seems like overkill for what is just a decorative effect unless the page is printed. And I'm not sure if you can even put tables inside a text-area, although again I haven't tested that.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.

Just to clarify, Method #1 is not using a table inside a textarea, but rather a table with each row containing an input box. When the text starts to overflow on the first line, it jumps to the input box in the 2nd line. Of course, the borders and background of the input box are invisible. So visually it looks like a textarea with lines.

Comment: And also, my users will be printing the page a lot. This page is something like a WYSIWYG kind of paper form filler.

Comment: Good thing. because markup does not render in a textarea, it just displays.  Is it just straight text going into the inputs?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying method 1. It seems like it'd be easier to test your CSS3 method first, and if it doesn't work out the way you'd like then give the 2nd and 1st methods a go.